# Reading large JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, sed

I have a large JSON files ~5GB, but instead of being made up of one JSON file it has several concatenated together.

```
{"created_at":"Mon Jan 13 20:01:57 +0000 2014","id":422820833807970304,"id_str":"422820833807970304"}
{"created_at":"Mon Jan 13 20:01:57 +0000     2014","id":422820837545500672,"id_str":"422820837545500672"}.....
```

With no new line between the curly brackets }{.

I tried replacing the curly brackets with a newline using sed then reading the file with:

```
data=[]
for line in open(filename,'r').readline():
data.append(json.loads(line))
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I read this file relatively quickly?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: When you try to use `data.append(json.loads(line))`; you are loading the entire 5 GB of data to your RAM.

Comment: OK. But even when I split the file into smaller files (50mb), I cannot read the separate JSON files.

Comment: This looks like a Mongo database dump.  Maybe put it back into a Mongo database and use the python interface to that?

Comment: Basically I have a lot of JSON files (where each JSON represents a document) together in one file. How do I split them up and parse them?

Comment: I thought it might be MongoDB, thanks! I haven't used MongoDB is it difficult to get your head around?

Comment: what if you split the huge line into many lines with `sed 's/}{/}\n{/g'`

Comment: That is the exact sed command that I used and it didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack. It does not load the whole file into memory. I really hope you use Python 3.

[DecodeLargeJSON.py](https://gist.github.com/niccokunzmann/10015194)

```
from DecodeLargeJSON import *
import io
import json

# create a file with two jsons
f = io.StringIO()
json.dump({1:[]}, f)
json.dump({2:"hallo"}, f)
print(repr(f.getvalue()))
f.seek(0) 

# decode the file f. f could be any file from here on. f.read(...) should return str
o1, idx1 = json.loads(FileString(f), cls = BigJSONDecoder)
print(o1) # this is the loaded object
# idx1 is the index that the second object begins with
o2, idx2 = json.loads(FileString(f, idx1), cls = BigJSONDecoder)
print(o2)
```

If you notice some objects that can not be decoded then you can tell me and we can find a solution.

**Disclaimer** This is not the valid and best solution. It is a hack that shows how it can be made possible.

**Discussion** Because it does not load the whole file into memory, regular expressions do not work. It also uses the Python implementation and not the C implementation. This could make it slower. I really hate how this easy task is hard. Hopefully somebody else points out a different solution.

Comment: Thanks, trying it out now. I use Python 2.7